# Массив времени в Java 8

Tags: java, java-8

Вход: 10 20
.......... 23 22

Задача такая: создать массив, где в i-м элементе было бы это время. То есть a[i].getMinutes - вернуло бы 20(22) соответственно. Пробовал создать массив типа Time, но Idea орет на a[i].getMinutes из-за устаревания(?).

В общем, мне нужен аналог DateTime из C#

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можете использовать этот класс [LocalDateTime](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDateTime.html)  Метод ,который вам нужен getMinute()

Comment: Только лучше `ZonedDateTime`, а то `LocalDateTime` тайм зону не учитывает.

Comment: @Suvitruf сильно зависит от задач. Очень часто предрочтительнее именно `LocalDateTime`,

Answer (score 1):

Насколько я понял, в данном примере нас интересует только время, поэтому предпочтительнее воспользоваться LocalTime, а не LocalDateTime, который хранит также и информацию о дате. Вот мой код на Java 8.

```
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    List <LocalTime> result = new ArrayList<>();
    Path p = Paths.get("newfile.txt");
    result = Files.lines(p).filter( str -> !str.isEmpty()).map(str -> {
        int hours = Integer.parseInt(str.split(" ")[0]);
        int minutes = Integer.parseInt(str.split(" ")[1]);
        return LocalTime.of(hours, minutes);
    }).collect(Collectors.toList());

    System.out.println(result);
}
```

Отмечу также, что при чтении файла почему-то добавляются пустые строки, поэтому я добавил фильтр.

Comment: Нашел ответ, почему добавляются пустые строки [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31048732/string-starts-with-an-empty-string)